# Youtube API Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response

Tags: api, youtube-api, cross-origin-read-blocking

When I try to use Youtube API I get this:

> error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin the header is present on the requested resource'

Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/ with MIME type text/html.

I kind of found a solution for that by running chrome using

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```

but I still can't get data from api in JSON from.
When I try to fetch the data I all i get is:

```
<!doctype html>
```

Google APIs Explorer
    
    </script-->

My link is https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&q=coding&type=video&_h=1&  and it works fine when I try it on Youtube APIs explorer.

Comment: Have you checked this [post](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/Error-No-Access-Control-Allow-Origin-header-is-present-on-the/td-p/350280) regarding this same error?